# Check for a latest version in Interval using php and json

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I want that WordPress will display a notice when new version is available after checking on json file.. But problem is i want all this function only run on  time interval like in every 2 days or 1 week ..don't want put extra burden  server.

```
function myfun_notice() {
$my_theme = wp_get_theme();
$a=$my_theme->get( 'Version' );
// Read 14 characters starting from the 21st character
$section = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/file.json', NULL, NULL, 16, 5);
if ($a !== $section){


        $return = '<div class="updated activation"><p><strong>';
        $my_theme = wp_get_theme();
        {
            $return .= sprintf( __( '%s New Version is available.', 'textdomain' ), $my_theme->get( 'Name' ) );
        }
        $return .= '</strong> <a href="' . home_url( '/' ) . '">' . __( 'Visit site', 'textdomain' ) . '</a></p>';

        $return .= '</p></div>';
        echo $return;
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'textdomain_notice' );
```

There is another code i found here but doesn't seem to work. So any one have idea of code that could work ?

```
<?php
$interval=60; //minutes
set_time_limit(0);
while (true)
{
$now=time();
include("the_script.php");
sleep($interval*60-(time()-$now));
}
?>
```

Comment: What is your question here?

Answer (score 0):

1. WordPress already shows when core update are available, by default. Are you trying to override the core behavior or just unaware it exists?

[image]

2. As of [WordPress 3.7](https://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress#Automatic_Background_Updates) it will even automatically update the site for you.
3. Even if you ran one request *per minute* you would not be "putting burden on the server".

If you want to control how automatic updates are handled by WordPress, see [Configuring Automatic Background Updates](https://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Automatic_Background_Updates) in the Code. You can completely disable, if desired, but this is not recommended lest you run your site on code with known security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Yes i already know that. If provide a custom plugin or theme to any one so that can only get update from my server then how to do this ?

Comment: OK you did not specify plugin/theme updates. It sounded like you wanted to alert when WordPress core updates were available.

Check out this answer I gave on another thread, I think it will be what you are looking for: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/183278/how-do-i-update-a-custom-theme/183285#183285